# SQL - hr database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to to select id, name and annual compensation.
I am running the script and everything is okay. I am asking to show me the result for id=100 and everything is perfect.
My problem is - if I want to check for id=300 (which is not in the table) I need to get result 'No employee with that ID' but it returns me 'no rows selected'. Is there something wrong with my last SELECT or with the EXCEPTION?

```
RETURN NUMBER IS
v_sal employees.salary%TYPE;
v_comm employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT salary,commission_pct INTO v_sal,v_comm
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id=v_empid;
RETURN (NVL(v_sal,0) * 12 + (NVL(v_comm,0) * NVL(v_sal,0) * 12));

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employee with that ID');
END get_annual_emp;

 



SELECT employee_id,last_name,
get_annual_emp(employee_id) "Annual Compensation"
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id=&v_empid;
```

Comment: Please provide a better title. This title does not describe the problem

Comment: Executing a SELECT that doesn't match any rows will not throw an exception, it's just an empty result set.

Comment: That's correct, @Lasse, in Oracle's SQL. But in PL/SQL it **will** raise the NO_DATA_FOUND error.

Comment: You appear to have not posted the first line (CREATE .....) of your PL/SQL.  It appears that you want to create a FUNCTION (as opposed to a PROCEDURE), but who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like exception handler doesn't do its job as you presumed it will.

A function is supposed to return some value. You're just **displaying** a message (on the screen, using `dbms_output.put_line` - that's not visible elsewhere, in a tool that doesn't support it).

Therefore, you could return null:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employee with that ID');
    RETURN null;
END get_annual_emp;
```

Or, raise an error:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No employee with that ID');
END get_annual_emp;
```

You can't actually return "No employee with that ID" as return value because it is a string, and your function returns a `number`. You *could* modify return value's datatype to `varchar2`, but - you do expect a number, don't you?

Comment: My task is to return that string and i thought I can do it like this.

Comment: No, you can not.